# Magento 2: How to get customer collection

Tags: magento2, collection, customer-group, dependency-injection

I got customer collection with help of objectManager but I don't know how to get customer collection via injecting a class in constructor(Dependency Injection).

So how we get customer collection using DI or factory method in Magento 2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **1) Use `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory` class to get customer collection**

```
<?php

protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    ...
}

/**
 * Get customer collection
 */
public function getCustomerCollection()
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}
```

Then you can call:

```
<?php

$customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection();

foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getEmail();
}
```

> **2) Use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` class to get customer by customerId or customer email**

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}

/**
 * Get Customer by id
 */
public function getCustomer($customerId)
{   
    return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
}

/**
 * Get Customer by email
 */
public function getCustomerByEmail($customerEmail)
{   
    return $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->get($customerEmail);
}
```

Comment: That works but loading the customer model is not necessary. Inject the autogenerated factory instead: `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory` and use `$this->customerCollectionFactory->create()` to get a new collection.

Comment: could u please elaborate with a code Fabian... It will be helpful

Comment: This works but it don't brings the custom customer attributes into the array. Neither loading the customer model with id is unable to fetch custom customer attributes into the array.

Comment: getCustomer function is not working